# "Unsolvable" Equations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I was just playing around with some equations the other day and losing interest I started writing down what were mostly "random" equations at first. But, I realized that there's something special about them, they don't have solutions! At least, as far as I could tell. On the surface it seems there should be solutions to them, seeing they *look* simple; at any rate, couldn't we just "define" objects which would satisfy these equations? Similar to what was done when complex numbers were introduced? I can't say; anywho, here is a sample of what I have:

$$
\tag{1} \sqrt{ix} = -1, \sqrt{ix} = -i, \sqrt{x} = -1 - i, \\ \sqrt{ix} = -1 - i, \sqrt{-ix} = -1 - i, \sqrt{-ix} = i - 1, \\ \sqrt{-ix} = -i
$$

What do you think? Can we get any solutions? Can we define solutions? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have to mention that I'm looking for solutions that would "force" the LHS of the equations to equal the RHS. I'm not an expert so I'm not sure if this is the right question to ask, but that's why I have it here :)

Comment: Write $x=re^{i\theta}$, $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ and substitute.

Comment: All of these have solutions in complex numbers. A boring fact is that all equations which dont simplify to 0=1 have solutions in C.

Comment: Curiously, what is your reasoning that lead you to conclude these don't have solutions?

Comment: @dls Isn't that a circular definition for $i$?

Comment: @Sam Find me an $x$ such that $\sqrt{x} = -1$.

Comment: @Holowitz Can I see your work for one of them?

Comment: I see your point, I think it's a branch cut problem.

Comment: @Holowitz I believe the standard definition is "$i = \sqrt{-1}$," yes?

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId For the 3rd one, just square it and multply out. the others, square them and multiply by i.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of branch cuts?

Comment: "...all equations which don't simplify to $0=1$ have solutions in $\bf C$." How about $e^x=0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ ;)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I rolled back your edit for the reason mentioned in my comment to oenamen's response.

Comment: @Holowitz, you can't multiply by $e^{-x}$ unless you know that's not tantamount to dividing by zero, which means you have to know independently that $e^x=0$ has no solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, but couldn't we determine that $e^x=0$ has no solution first, and then proceed to reduce the equation to $1=0$ by multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$? Going all the way to the point of $1=0$ would be superfluous, but it is possible. For instance, $e^x=0\implies e^{x+1}=0\implies e^x=e^{x+1}$. This, by definition, means that $\log e^x = \log e^{x+1} \implies x=x+1 \implies 0=1$. Even just noting that, since $e^x>0$, we have that $e^x\ne0$ and therefore we can multiply each side by $e^{-x}$ to get $1=0$ is enough, I suppose.

Comment: @process91, the trouble with this line of argument can perhaps be seen in this example: over the reals, $x^2=-1$ reduces to $1=0$ by rewriting it as $x^2+1=0$ and then multiplying by $1/(x^2+1)$. If you can do that sort of thing then there is no nontrivial content to the statement that equations that don't simplify to $1=0$ have solutions in $\bf C$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That makes sense. So the reason the OP's original expressions are false is purely due to the use of the $\sqrt{}$ sign, indicating the positive branch, correct? Moreover, if one decides to go along the negative branch, one must continue on that branch. That is, one cannot mix results from both branches. For instance, $x^{1/2}=-1$ has $x=1$ as a solution, on the negative branch. Then, if we were allowed to mix branches, we could write $x^{1/2}=1$ also, and then multiply the two together to get $x=-1$ and now $1=-1$. This needs to be avoided, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question shows that you are rigorously thinking about these concepts, which is good. Let's take a simple example which is similar in concept to those equations you've mentioned:

$$\sqrt x = -1$$

Because it is convenient, a generally agreed upon custom of mathematics is to denote a *principal* square root of a number by the $\sqrt{}$ symbol. For complex numbers, this is defined as follows ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)):

Let $x=ze^{i\varphi}$ where $\varphi$ is the principal angle ($\varphi\in(-\pi,\pi]$), then $\sqrt x = \sqrt z e^{i \varphi/2}=\sqrt z [\cos \tfrac \varphi 2 + i\sin \tfrac \varphi 2]$.

From this definition, we can see that the real part of $\sqrt x$ must be positive.
Thus the equation $\sqrt x = -1$ has no solution in the complex numbers, when $\sqrt {}$ is taken to be the principal root. If we wanted to define a new number field for which $\sqrt x = -1$ has a solution, say $x=j$, then we would quickly run into trouble, as squaring both sides leads to the conclusion that $j=1$. Thus new rules would have to be created regarding how to treat the multiplication of square roots in our new number system, and very likely such a system would not end up being consistent.

In addition, such an extension does not yield as useful a result as the complex numbers, since we find that $x=1$ *is* a solution if we consider the multivalued square root function instead of the principal square root.

The complex numbers were introduced in order to create a field in which all algebraic equations had solutions. A good place to continue your investigation would be this thread:
http://www.physicsforums.com/archive/index.php/t-315935.html

---

A small comment about why I dropped the $1=0$ approach: Now, although some equations may be able to be transformed to $1=0$, and thus the original equation was false within the given field, this is not reason in and of itself to dissuade one from an extension of the number system, such as the complex were to the reals. This was pointed out to me by Gerry Myerson in the comments above. To see why, consider a situation where the only number system is the reals, as it was before complex numbers were introduced. Now one may write an equation such as $x^2+1=0$ and use the following logic: $x^2>0 \implies x^2+1>1 \implies x^2+1\ne0$ and now, dividing our original equation by $x^2+1$ is valid, since $x^2+1\ne0$, and hence we have $1=0$.

So what we have shown is that, in $\mathbb R$, $x^2+1=0$ has no solution, but this did not prevent the extension of the reals to the complex numbers and so it should not serve as a reason to prevent an extension based on the equation $\sqrt x = -1$. Similarly to the way that the complex numbers made the inequality $x^2>0$ not true, our new number system would make the inequality $\sqrt x > 0$ not true.

Comment: That clears up everything, thanks! I had a feeling there was some mistake with my assumptions.

Comment: I was going through the answer again, and "$\sqrt{x} = -1\ ... \implies \sqrt{1} = -1$" caught my eye. This is valid under the assumption that we are not considering the principal branch of the square root function; however, this is not the case with (1) in the OP. Though, I think what you stated in the paragraph prior, "... $\sqrt{x} = -1$" has no solution, addresses the question at any rate. On a more informal note, doesn't it make you wonder? Seems pretty suspect to me that a construction of this sort seems allowable, but doesn't admit a solution still.

Comment: Actually, I think you're conclusion about the equation entailing a contradiction seems to be on mark, though, for a different reason than one concerning arithmetic. If we examine closely my OP, we find that I have demanded we be able to find solutions to equations of the form "$\sqrt{x} = -1$" while *at the same time* looking at the principal branch of the square root function. This is a contradiction, by definition. We could only arrive at the situation "1=0" if there was no contradiction as the one that was inherent to begin with. I hope this is right.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Look carefully at the step that falls between the statement $\sqrt x = -1$ and $\sqrt 1 = -1$, where (by squaring both sides) we arrive at the conclusion that $x=1$. Thus, we are just substituting to arrive at $\sqrt 1 = -1$. You are correct, in that this is already false, and the proof could have stopped there, but I just continued on to reach a more obviously false statement. It is a thought provoking question.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId A modification to my answer may be forthcoming, pending a response from Gerry... stay tuned.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId I just made a major rewrite to my answer, which hopefully will provide more clarity and information.

Comment: Very interesting. It gives new light to the problem; though, I believe the reasoning may be subtly flawed. I'm not sure yet; I will look at the whole thing again, gather my thoughts, and post an answer to the question as it would be too long for a comment (Maybe we should turn it into a Wiki?). I have a few more ideas about what's going on. Also, I believe the whole thing can do with a bit more formalism, so I vote we should either bring the question to moderator attention and/or move it to Math Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Let's just look at one of the equations (the rest of them can be handled similarly),
$$\sqrt{i x} = -1.$$
Squaring both sides we find
$i x = 1$, so $x = -i$.
Checking with the original equation we find
$$\sqrt{i(-i)} = \sqrt{1}.$$
If we interpret $\sqrt{}$ as the *principal root*, then $\sqrt{1} = 1$, and $x=-i$ is not a solution.
However, if we interpret $\sqrt{}$ as the *multivalued root* then there are two roots of $1$, $1$ *and* $-1$, since $1^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$.
In this case $x=-i$ is a solution.

The square root is multivalued.
This is something we see even with real numbers!

Comment: I was just hoping that there may be some way of "forcing" the LHS of the equation to equal -1. I'm no analysis expert, so I may be completely off about this after all. Maybe I ought to edit the OP to reflect this. But, thanks for the response.

Comment: @oenamen I hate to disagree, but there really isn't a solution if you use the expression $\sqrt{}$ with it's standard meaning, since $\sqrt{ix}>0$. If $x=-i$ is a solution, then we can simplify the expression to $1=-1$, which is obviously not true.

Comment: @process91: I agree it is confusing to use the notation $\sqrt{}$ for the multivalued root. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: Glad to help. As I clarified in my answer, if we interpret the root as the multivalued root these equations have solutions in $\mathbb{C}$. For example, $1^{1/2} = e^{i k \pi}$, where $k=0,1$, is the typical definition of the multivalued root of $1\in\mathbb{C}$. $k$ tells us which branch we're on. $k=0$ is the principal branch. For $k=1$ this "forces" the LHS of the equation of interest to be $-1$. If you consider only the principal branch you only know half of the function $z^{1/2}$.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: See a diagram of the Riemann surface showing the two branches of the square root [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface).

Answer (score 3):

If your $\sqrt{}$ denotes the *principal branch* of the square root, you are correct in that this never has a negative real part, and when its real part is $0$ the imaginary part is nonnegative.